# List of local variables inconsistently updating

Tags: python, list, variables

I have a large project that creates variables assigned to financial outcomes of products, given certain parameter changes. I label all these variables consistently as

rtn_xxxx1_0,
rtn_xxxx2_0,
rtn_xxxx3_0,
rtn_xxxx1_p10,
rtn_xxxx2_p10,
rtn_xxxx3_p10

for the return variables of 3 products in "0" shock environment and a "+10%" shock environment.

I then capture all the variables for the defined shocks using :

```
 list_of_rtns_00 = []
 list_of_rtns_00.extend(value for name, value in locals().items() if name.endswith('_0'))
```

which generates a list of  all my variables that end with '_0'

Occasionally I need to amend the formulas that make up these variables (I have about 30 per outcome) but I have noticed when I do that the part of my code that generates the list of all the variables omits the variable I've just changed (ie only returns a list of 29 variables and not 30)

I've spent forever(ish) trying to sort this and have found a fix where I rename all the suffixes of the variables :

rtn_xxxx1_0 becomes rtn_xxxx1_p0
rtn_xxxx2_0 becomes rtn_xxxx1_p0

and so on.

If I do that and then generates a list for all variables ending in 'p0' then the list returns 30 variables again.

I've no idea why - and I've no idea how to fix - renaming the variables everytime I make a change makes no sense to me so I'm fearful something else in my code is incorrect.

Adding more code due to comments :

```
 if product_list_grouped_wo_barriers['Net WO Return'].loc[product_list_grouped_wo_barriers['ISIN'].str.contains('XXXXXXXXXXXX', regex=False)].values.item() <= -.4:
    rtn_139_0 = 1-abs(product_list_grouped_wo_barriers['Net WO Return'].loc[product_list_grouped_wo_barriers['ISIN'].str.contains('XXXXXXXXXXXX', regex=False)].values.item())
else:
    rtn_139_0 = ((139-100)/100)+1
```

as an example - I find the product in a table using its index (referenced by an identifier (XXXX'd out here)). I then have some outcomes dependent on where what the Net WO Return is. I basically end up witha value for rtn_139_0 givne different Net WO Returns....this helps me build up my "outcomes" later (using the lists of the variables I'm trying to compile.)

Regarding the comment to use a dicionary instead of local variables. I'm very much a beginner so fear I may have gone about this the incorrect way. May you divulge more information about the dictionary set up and referencing ? How does it differ to local variables ?

Comment: I can't help but think your approach is fundamentally wrong. Use a `dict` to store the financial outcomes of products instead of relying on `locals()` (which is `dict`).

Comment: Post more of your code.